# Django python pisa no module utils

Tags: python, django, pisa

```
No module named utils

python2.7/pisa-3.0.33-py2.7.egg/sx/pisa3/pisa_parser.py in <module>, line 29
```

I'm trying to use pisa to generate pdfs from html. please let me know if you've encountered this error before.

```
__author__ = "$Author: holtwick $"
__date__ = "$Date: 2007-10-09 12:58:24 +0200 (Di, 09 Okt 2007) $"
from pisa_util import *
from pisa_reportlab import *
import pisa_default
import pisa_parser
 ...
import re
import urlparse
import types
from reportlab.platypus.paraparser import ParaParser, ParaFrag, ps2tt, tt2ps, ABag
from reportlab.platypus.paragraph import cleanBlockQuotedText
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `pisa` - it has become `xhtml2pdf`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have no module Utils installed. See your "pisa" dependencies documentation. It usually says what does it need.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need [python setup tools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools)